# How to resolve "ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, sys, python-packaging

I have the following problem with my project, help me please! Here is the structure of my package:

```
/pkg

/pkg/__init__.py
/pkg/sub1/__init__.py
/pkg/sub2/__init__.py

/pkg/sub1/foo1.py
/pkg/sub2/foo2.py
```

Here is implementation of foo1.py:

```
from ..sub2 import foo2

def f():
    print("Hello!")
```

When I run foo1 I get error: **ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package**.

I can solve it doing the following adjustment:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.pardir))

from sub2 import foo2
def f():
    print("Hello!")
```

But I wonder if there is a way to do it without importing sys and appending parent directory in it.

I heard that if I had .py file '/pkg/start.py' for example which called my foo1 module, then two dots would work. However, is there any way to call foo2 from foo1 directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me, that without adding pkg to my PATH it is impossible to import modules from sub2 in sub1. Here is explanation why:

> Relative imports use a module's **name** attribute to determine that module's position in the package hierarchy. If the module's name does not contain any package information (e.g. it is set to '**main**') then relative imports are resolved as if the module were a top level module, regardless of where the module is actually located on the file system.

[Here is official python web site, where it is explained](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#relative-imports-and-name)