# Problems with relative path import in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, relative-path

I have a project with this directory structure
[image: PythonProjectDirectoryStructure]

I want to import a def from `functions.py` from `notebook01.ipynb`.
I followed the documentation of relative path import [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) and studied the answers in [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path).

I tried to write `from .Modules.functions import fibonacci`, (With one dot before the `Modules` folder) I got the following error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-be5f30231faa> in <module>
----> 1 from .Modules.functions import fibonacci

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.Modules'; '__main__' is not a package
```

And I tried to add two or three dots before the `Modules` folder `from ..Modules.functions import fibonacci` then I got the error

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-8d1656059c1f> in <module>
----> 1 from ..Modules.functions import fibonacci

ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

I have added the `__init__.py` files at each level of the directory structure as suggested by the documentations][2](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) as you see, but no luck at all!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046660/how-to-resolve-valueerror-attempted-relative-import-beyond-top-level-package

Comment: Try `sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(".."))`. Then `import Modules.functions as functions`.

Comment: Thanks for all replies, but I wonder if I should add the absolute path to the system! and what if I shared the problems with some friends, should everyone change the code to include the absolute path?

Comment: Also, what will happen if the user's prevailages are limited, and can't change the path? (I use Windows)

Comment: I found a good workaround  **WITHOUT adding to the system path** [here in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll be honest: relative import could be hell. That's why Python 3 does absolute imports by default (https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html).

If you use Python 3 - make all your packages absolute.

If you still use Python 2 you can switch default behavior by adding the following line at the top:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Actually, I stopped using python 2, and using 3.7 now.

Comment: It is sad to know that no solution to do it in python 3.x!

Comment: I found a good workaround  **WITHOUT adding to the system path** [here in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)